# Python script apply_modifier on boolean modifier is very slow

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I got a lot of scripts that run... And 99% of the time is lost on one operation in one of my scripts :

```py
def func_cut_boolean_modifier(obj,nameplate_size):
    active_obj=obj
    func_activate_object(active_obj)
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=True)
    remover_element = "remover " + nameplate_size
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = bpy.data.objects[remover_element]
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].solver = 'EXACT'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Boolean")
    func_activate_object(active_obj)
```

The `modifier_apply` is eating all. It's a simple function on a boolean. How can solve that problem?
Thanks for the help...

Comment: Yes, Boolean is slow. You can try changing the solver to `'FAST'`, or see if you can achieve the result without using boolean... It's hard to advice anything else without seeing what you use your boolean on.

Comment: I'm already using fast :( I use it to remove 2 symetrical parts with 2 cubes. I have a question. If I add more vertices to the cubes, will the boolean function work faster? for now they are simple cubes cutting complex and deformed shapes.

Comment: Your code says you're using `'EXACT'`. If you're cutting with cubes, perhaps you can just write a script in Python that makes two plane cuts where the cubes would cut, removes all vertices in a given coordinate range, and then create faces from vertices laying on the planes that were used to cut. This should be much faster than boolean. A boolean will probably work slower if you have more vertices...